# CSS3 Columns - Force non breaking/splitting element?

Tags: css

I'm using some CSS3 columns (`column-count: 2;column-gap: 20px;`) to split some content into two columns. In my content I have a `<p>`, followed by a `<blockquote>`, followed by another `<p>`.

My question: Is there a way of preventing my `<blockquote>` (or any other specified element) from splitting into two columns?

For example, currently my `<blockquote>` is partially in column 1, and partially in column 2.

[image: Blockquote split onto multiple columns]

Ideally I'd like to make it so the `<blockquote>` stays together in either column 1 or 2.

[image: Blockquote maintained in column]

Any idea if this can be achieved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Add `display:inline-block;` to the item you want to prevent from splitting.

Comment: This is a very helpful tip. Thank you. But unfortunately this doesn't work with the jQuery Columns Plugin. Maybe you know a workaround for this by chance, too? Would be very interesting: http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/

Comment: also doesn't work if you're columns are made up of long list elements

Comment: Also, you need to remove any floats you have on the element, or it will split even with `display:inline-block`

Comment: FYI, this solution **doesn't work if you're using order lists**. When you apply `display:inline-block;` it hides the list item (numbers for example).

Comment: Thank you, but this does not work with Opera. I know, Opera is not a very popular browser, but still...

Answer (score 51):

In theory the property you are looking for is...

```
blockquote {
  column-break-inside : avoid;
}
```

However, last time I checked it wasn't properly implemented in Webkit, no idea about firefox. I've had more luck with:

```
blockquote {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

As the renderer treats it as an image and doesn't break it among columns.

Comment: Works in webkit with -webkit- prefix.

Comment: Nowadays just use `break-inside: avoid;`

Answer (score 10):

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-inside), the correct solution is

```
blockquote {
  break-inside: avoid-column;
}
```

However this is [not yet implemented](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-page-break) in all browsers, so a practical solution is:

```
blockquote {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Update 2023: According to MDN, it's now almost fully supported everywhere https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-inside

Answer (score 7):

Just general FYI for others that bump into this forum and need a solution for Firefox.

At the moment writing this, Firefox 22.0 didn't support `column-break-inside` property even with `-moz-` prefix.

But the solution is quite simple: Just use `display:table;`. You can also do **`display:inline-block;` The problem with these solutions is that the list items will lose their list style item or bullet icon.

**Also, one problem I've experienced with `display:inline-block;` is that if the text in two consecutive list items is very short, the bottom item will wrap itself up and inline with the one above it.

`display:table;` is the least worst of both solutions.

More info here: http://trentwalton.com/2012/02/13/css-column-breaks/