# Columns CSS white space

Tags: html, css

I have just started using css columns. I have used a solution from a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506783/css3-columns-force-non-breaking-splitting-element/8507148) 
in order to keep paragraphs intact between columns.

```
<div class="columns">
<p>Text to be kept in a single block and not split between two different columns</p>
</div>

.columns p{display:inline-block;}
```

Adding `display:inline-block;` elements within the columns, prevents them from being split between the bottom and top of next column.

However viewing in Chrome, I am finding that I am being left with a lot of white space at the bottom of the columns.

Here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/r4ahhbj8/1/

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but I'm not sure what else I can show. I have updated my question.

Comment: oh, and my problem is, I don't want the white space at the bottom of columns.

Comment: How about a jsFiddle.net example showing the issue?

Comment: Hi, The issue arrises in Chrome. here is a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/r4ahhbj8/1/

Comment: Interesting problem.  I haven't played with columns much. If you know that you want to break after 2 paragraphs, you can use .columise p+p to trigger a break point, as in: http://jsfiddle.net/9zd75ez5/1/
 but that of course won't lend it self very well to dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

The columns should have width and it seems like the `<p>` are not needed. Here is the demo in Fiddle:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/r4ahhbj8/3/

I hope this helped you!

**Edited: With `<p>`**

Removed `display:inlineblock` from `<p>`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/r4ahhbj8/4/ .

Comment: Hi, just tried changing some of the text on the fiddle and it doesn't seem to work as you suggest. There are no paragraph separations at all.

Comment: Hi there! I see your point. I removed `display:inlineblock` for `<p>`. Check it out http://jsfiddle.net/r4ahhbj8/4/ . Maybe you should play with `<p>` in this case.