# Distribute boxes of various heights evenly across flexbox columns

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox

I have some boxes of the same width, but of different heights (depending on their content — they are notes of title+text), and a container of auto height (willing to scroll).
The idea is to distribute the notes in the container across the columns, so that it looks like Google Keep.
For now I am using flexbox rows, but I'm loosing space:

[image: example with flexbox rows]

My current CSS looks like:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  padding: 10px;
}
.note {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
.note>div {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

The problem is that if I switch to `flex-direction: column`, because of the `height: auto` of my flexbox container, the notes make only one column, because they don't see any reason to wrap.
Calculating the container's height in Javascript would be quite hard to do without rendering the notes first (and I'm using React...)
Am I missing something here?

Here is the result I'm looking to achieve:

[image]

I don't want to use jQuery, and I'd love to avoid Javascript...

Comment: Are you missing something? No, as you said,...if the column doesn't have a definite height it has no *reason* to wrap.

Comment: I know, I'm looking for a way to make them wrap...

Comment: Then a height has to be involved...even if it's 100vh...something. Otherwise you are looking at a JS solution.

Comment: Alternatively, abandon flexbox and consider CSS Columns

Comment: Problem is, with flexboxes, if for example I set the height to 100vh, if there are too many notes to fit in, the extra ones will be ignored and not shown... I looked at CSS columns also, but it breaks my blocks into pieces of text

Comment: With CSS columns it does not keep my notes (blocks) intact (not split), or did I miss the way to wrap only notes, not content, with css columns?

Comment: I'll try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8507148/1052033

Comment: CSS columns indeed are a good solution! Thanks :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ended up abandoning flexboxes and used [columns](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/columns/) instead:

```css
.container {
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
.note {
  display: inline-block; /* important to wrap notes not content */
  width: 100%;
}
.note>div {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

[Use inline-block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8507148/1052033) notes, and [don't hide the overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29624610/1052033).

[image]

Comment: But all elements are sorted vertically, rather than alternating horizontally.

Comment: this breaks my card into half while changing coluns any solution to that?